# Нарисовать сердце в стиле ASCII-art на основе ввода пользователя

Tags: java, консоль, символы, рисование

Программа Java должна печатать сердечки в стиле ASCII-art на основе ввода `N`, заданного пользователем.

**Информация:**

- Символы для печати: ♡ ♥
- Печать *верхней* и *нижней* части сердца может быть выполнена отдельно.
- Решение должно быть основано на циклах for, но не обязательно.
- `N` определяет верхнюю часть сердца:

  1. *На наклонных внешних сторонах вверху находятся `N` сердец.*
  2. *В плоских частях вверху находятся `N` сердец.*
  3. *Зазор между двумя плоскими частями имеет ширину `N` сердец.*

**Примеры:**

- [N = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fICix.png)
- [N = 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzKm5.png)
- [N = 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zIEP.png)
- [N = 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkiUf.png)

**Мой код на текущий момент:**

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of hearts you want to print");
    int userInput = scan.nextInt();

    printTop(userInput);
}
```

```java
public static void printTop(int userInput) {
    String row = "";
    int width = 2 * (userInput - 1) + 3 * userInput;
    for (int height = 0; height < userInput; height++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput - 1; i++) {
            row += "♡";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
            row += "♥";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
            row += "♡";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput; i++) {
            row += "♥";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < userInput - 1; i++) {
            row += "♡";
        }
        row += "\n";
    }
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

**Мысли:**

- Первая строка сердца рассчитывается на основе:

  ```
  2 * (userInput - 1) + 3 * userInput
  ```
- *Заполненные сердечки* должны увеличиваться на 2 на каждой строке.
- *Центральные сердечки* нужно уменьшать на 2 для каждой строки.
- *Пустые сердечки* по бокам нужно уменьшать на 1 для каждой строки.

**Вопросы:**

- Как заставить разные виды сердец выполнять свою "работу" на каждой строке?

Answer (score 2):

#### Рисуем сердце в стиле ASCII-art, заполненное и пустое

Представим *систему координат* и нарисуем фигуру, которая состоит из двух полукругов и одного полуромба.

[image: два полукруга и один полуромб]

Картинки 1 и 2:

[image: Сердце в стиле ASCII-art заполненное] [image: Сердце в стиле ASCII-art пустое]

Фигура 1 - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZGxbsIwEIb3PMUvBmQnclR16JLSN2BirDoYCNQ0OCE2yFbhQTp26Iv1RVLbBJQ0ouoNd9bd/3/2yRt@4KyscrlZvjVNtZ8XYoFFwZXClAuJ9wgu2r7SXLtyKMUSWzclM10LuX5@Aa/XirZiH0JqSEzwkF1bq7IG8X3r@kxmrj5OcI8Y/pwkXXtPb7y@1ZmOxzhPzxEuXoGQQL7DeDwYX4J4MnUr6tdU7WpNiEkkjUNGAhtb6hnyJuASxyOGKBZQrI@iNPoLYvEUnnwG8bkihl6XBYO94Z9ZpfNtWu51WrnP0GT0/fGFEc0G6rxQ@b8RnwPEb1UhSUdxis751DQ/)

```java
int n = 6;
for (int y = -n; y <= 2 * n; y++) {
    for (int x = -2 * n; x <= 2 * n; x++)
        if ((y <= 0 &&
                ((int) Math.sqrt((x+n)*(x+n) + y*y) <= n
                        || (int) Math.sqrt((x-n)*(x-n) + y*y) <= n))
                || (y > 0 && Math.abs(x) <= 2 * n - y))
            System.out.print("♥ ");
        else
            System.out.print("♡ ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Вывод 1:

```
♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡
♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡
♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥
♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥
♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥
♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥
♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡
♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
```

---

Фигура 2 - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZGxTsMwEIb3PMWvDpWdyBFiYAnhDZg6Iga3TYvb1AmxW9mifRBGBl6MFwm2m6KEqIgb7qy7///skzf8wFlVF3Kz3LZtvZ@XYoFFyZXCIxcSbxFcdH2luXblUIkldm5KZroRcv30DN6sFe3EPoTUkMhxl/20VlUD4vvW9ZnMXL3PcYsY/pwkfftAb7y@05mexzjPwBEuXoGQQL7BdDoaX4J4MnUr6pdUvTaaEJNIGoeMBDa2FHkOeRVwieMRYxQLKDZEURr9BbF4CE8@g/hcERN8YVkw2Cv@mVW62KXVXqe1@wxNJl/vn5jQbKQuSlX8G/ExQvxWlZL0FKfonE9t@w0)

```java
int n = 6;
for (int y = -n; y <= 2 * n; y++) {
    for (int x = -2 * n; x <= 2 * n; x++)
        if ((y <= 0 &&
                ((int) Math.sqrt((x+n)*(x+n) + y*y) == n
                        || (int) Math.sqrt((x-n)*(x-n) + y*y) == n))
                || (y > 0 && Math.abs(x) == 2 * n - y))
            System.out.print("♥ ");
        else
            System.out.print("♡ ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Вывод 2:

```
♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡
♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡
♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥
♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥
♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥
♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥
♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡
♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♥ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡
```

---

<sup>См. [Draw a heart in ASCII-art style, filled and empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68170309/16649492)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать пакет `java.awt`, чтобы нарисовать эти символы `♥ ♡` в виде черно-белой картинки:

[image: картинка]

А затем вывести 2D массив пикселей в виде символов, из которых состоит эта картинка:

```
        ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡         ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡                 ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡         ♡ ♡ ♡           
      ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡     ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡             ♡         ♡     ♡       ♡         
    ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡   ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡           ♡           ♡   ♡           ♡       
    ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡         ♡             ♡ ♡             ♡     
    ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡         ♡             ♡               ♡     
    ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡         ♡                             ♡     
    ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡             ♡                           ♡     
      ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡             ♡                         ♡       
        ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡                 ♡                     ♡         
        ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡                     ♡                 ♡           
          ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡                       ♡                 ♡           
            ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡                         ♡             ♡             
              ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡                             ♡         ♡               
                ♡ ♡ ♡ ♡                                 ♡     ♡                 
                  ♡ ♡                                   ♡   ♡                   
                  ♡                                       ♡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVXNbtNAEL7nKYac7MR1S4@EAi20VSSgVdpLFUVoG6@TDYlt2RuSCiH1BwRSkXrm2AP3UlEILaSvsH6FvkiZXa9TO6mleL3fznzz7ezspEPekTk/oF7HeXt7y3qBH3LoIGiTAbdLlcI05Poet9fwVaOeQ8Pn@EWHfNaO9UiL2it916UhdapyVikUgv5ulzWh2SVRBK8I8@B9AfDReMQJx@Gdzxzo4aqxxUPmteoNIGErMrWxfJjH6w3E25SEPIIldJWW2/4mG9JuZBRvvn2/@XZatMCjA5B6Dfmyt1Zr1TVLAfbmy@XqawsWF00LFszKhHt@HsR5fCzOxVj8nKCuH4KhwkLoD@CRDp0VJZ9E8UqfdTE7EO2iNKkgBxuZYFlqYEiL5GZuVT7Rrk0CPCXHYPBgCRbgKeAOT6GIDkWA4hQhc8FAF4YnNNxwZTJOiyY8gbmHs9RbexGnPdvvcztAjbzroWuG70MheathvlRKFkrwLCAh6cm8gxjFB/EnmS3xT5zFJ4DTw3gfgUtxBoheSWxfmiF2Ls7QbBSfTDG5OIm/KLOP8WHqJsaKKnW9FCOID8WFuJQxxNkUR@BA4iEFHInrCcs1clzgZKzcxkrcL5SRzEcWnjiIHwhexV/jL2Ik/qmFc3GBm0HwKP6Msi/QamESMqS8H3qw@ALEX9z2ARqOJM01DigPra/w9we5R@I3oPRxEjo@jj9JVq0F93aYy5gOMK9GfSXSep8q86SsJJrUNLiWNMU8ZOty5rpCkw91Yc6sGa7donw7JF6Eddkz8HK4pBtRPWQqo0abnHitLoVdv@858hYqX13rCjOUNAxnyhWNZTik2AFzeBudExY7mZblWZZgMW/apqzV5ne2ej5rnGs8oJoRLM3UvkxAztJQwS0dx8ov2ts7m6tvVna28VV9vVzbyexjPSRBmzUjLIaW/kSVxh1sJiJkFlIwm4fUyY4oV93KvW/RCckgyW6SV9x1OU3FUE3n0ulerqEp/dUNexAyTg2lxIJi4LXSBsm61Cgipy0xM39AqvCCZloxEkny06irdDUqhXs6GXapCg6PdS7xu1w27297ncS4g8aKED@nbdOuNklibX3F6GCxm7CEzsM1/cx6qb@X5rDOGvVOAwM9vFOrLzCuVnST@3B7@x8)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[][] hearts = stringToPixels("♥♡", new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 22), 0);
  // вывод
  for (int[] row : hearts) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i : row)
      sb.append(i != 0 ? "♡ " : "  ");
    if (sb.indexOf("♡") > -1)
      System.out.println(sb);
  }
}
```

```java
/**
 * @param str исходная строка для рисования
 * @param f   шрифт для отрисовки текста
 * @param pd  отступ для предосторожности, в большинстве случаев 0
 * @return 2D массив пикселей, из которых состоит строка
 */
static int[][] stringToPixels(String str, Font f, int pd) {
  FontRenderContext ctx = new FontRenderContext(f.getTransform(), false, false);
  Rectangle bounds = f.getStringBounds(str, ctx).getBounds();
  int width = bounds.width + pd * 2;
  int height = bounds.height + pd * 2;
  BufferedImage image =
          new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
  Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
  graphics.setFont(f);
  graphics.drawString(str, pd + bounds.x, pd - bounds.y);
  //ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("str.png"));
  int[][] pcx = new int[height][width];
  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
      if (image.getRGB(j, i) == 0xFFFFFFFF)
        pcx[i][j] = 1;
  return pcx;
}
```

---

<sup>См. [Draw a heart in ASCII-art style based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68309402/16649492)</sup>